# Sed command inside TCL script

Tags: sed, tcl

Help me understand the syntax sed.I removed single quotes, but the code still does not work.

```
set id [open file.txt]
# send the request, get a lot of data
set tok [::http::geturl "http://example.com"-channel $id] 
# cut out the necessary data between two words
exec sed s/{"data1":\(.*\)/data2\1/ $id 
close $id
set ir [open file.txt]
set phone [read $ir]
close $ir
puts $phone
```

The problem is that I get data from a query of the following kind

```
 {"id":3876,"form":"index","time":21,"data":"2529423","service":"Atere","response":"WAIT"}
```

The brace is an element of the syntax of the language, and I need to cut exactly the value between the word and the brace. How to implement this in a script.

Comment: 44 Q/As when searching here for `using sed [tcl]`. Some look very promising. Best to also update your Q to show required output. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is rather confused, as (a) you are passing a file handle to the sed command.  That's not going to work.  (b) you are passing an input channel to http rather than an output channel (try opening the file for writing).

About the underlying problem.
If you are receiving basic JSON data back as shown.

a) You can use a JSON parser: [tcllib's json module](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/json/json.html)

b) Convert it to a form that Tcl can parse as a dictionary

```
# Assuming the JSON data is in the $data variable, and there's no
# other data present.  This also assumes the data is very basic 
# there are no embedded commas.  Many assumptions means this
# code is likely to break in the future.  A JSON parser would
# be a better choice.
set data "\{"
append data {"id":3876,"form":"index","time":21,"data":"2529423","service":"Atere","response":"WAIT"}
append data "\}"
regsub -all {[{}:",]} $data { } data
set mydatadict $data 
puts [dict get $mydatadict id]
```

**Edit:**

For http processing:

```
set tok [::http::geturl "http://example.com"]
set data [::http::data $tok]
::http::cleanup $tok
```

Comment: Yes, on another resource, I was also indicated this. Thanks for the answer. And how can I add text to the dictionary from the file? Or is it better to directly from the http query？

Comment: Many thanks! I did according to your advice and it all worked.

Comment: A possible alternative that doesn't add a lot of spurious blanks: `set data [regexp -all -inline {[^"{}:,]+} $data]`. The blanks don't bother the `dict` commands, of course. Note that more cleverness is needed if the keys or values have blanks in them.

Comment: Your answer above works great with a series of kinds `{example, answer, example, answer, example, answer}`
But there was a problem with the data, which is output in the form of an expression `[{example, answer, example, answer, example, answer}]`
This data is displayed as a string enclosed in square brackets. How do I configure it so that it would also be read in the dictionary?

Comment: I'm trying to cut off the first and last quartet bracket with a squeeze command, but  
`set data [::http::data $tok]
set data_string [string trim $data "[]"]
puts $data_string`

but I do not know how to correctly print square brackets